# Is there a tool that was specifically created to easily draw and generate probabilistic graphical models?

Tags: graphics, tikz-graphdrawing

Do you know of any drag-and-drop tool to draw probabilistic graphical models? I don't want to write code and use the usual trial-and-error approach to draw correctly the graphical models and place well the letters, arrows, circles, or surrounding boxes. Is there a tool that was specifically created to draw PGMs that knows how to draw them well and allows us to manipulate them visually and export them as `tikzpicture` or images (png, jpg or pdf).

I have already looked at [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/16750/82135), but those solutions either do not provide a drag-and-drop tool or the generation of the graphical models doesn't look like I want. I want them to look similar to the graphical model in figure 1 of [the VAE paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6114.pdf).

Comment: This isn't exactly a duplicate but, given the resolution (see answer), it seems reasonable to treat it as such. I guess otherwise it is probably off-topic? Or maybe just underspecified?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I missed [one of the answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/38042/82135) in the linked post that suggests a tool similar to what I was looking for, although it doesn't provide the ability to drag-and-drop the objects of the graphical model, i.e. https://github.com/jluttine/tikz-bayesnet, but it should be good enough because it was specifically created to draw and generate PGMs.

Comment: So, is this an answer or an edit? If you think that your question is a duplicate, please mark it as such.